# Weird php error with inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance

Basically I have a bunch of classes inheriting from one another. So to better illustrate my point:

```
IndexController extends fController extends fControllerAbstract extends 
MoorActionController extends MoorAbstractController
```

So, the highest parent in that group is MoorAbstractController.

In every _*construct() , there is a parent::*_construct(); except in the bottom most child class -- IndexController

So the problem that I'm having is this (which I solved with a weird fix, but I want to know what's going on):

I have a field member in fController that IndexController inherits, yet the value doesn't get passed down for some weird reason. So, echoing $this->field_member in IndexController doesn't output anything. The field member itself gets passed down, but not the value it contains. The way I fixed this error, is by calling parent::__construct() last inside of the __construct() in fController.

The weirder part is that when testing it one level upwards (fControllerAbstract passing down a field member to fController) works completely fine. I am really not sure what's going on.

Here's some code:

```
//WORKS
class fController extends fControllerAbstract
{
protected $field_member = null;

public function __construct()
{        
    $this->field_member="asdasdas";

    parent::__construct();

}
}


//DOESNT WORK
class fController extends fControllerAbstract
 {
protected $field_member = null;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->field_member = "asdasdas"; //value doesnt get passed


}
}
//IndexController/ // /  //
class IndexController extends fController {

public function beforeAction()
{

}

public function home()
{
    echo $this->field_member; 
}
}

// fControllerAbstract ////////
class fControllerAbstract extends MoorActionController
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}


}
```

Comment: Could you please write a 10-lines code that illustrates the issue? It should work

Comment: Is the property in fController that doesn't show up in IndexController public, protected, or private?  It cannot be private if you want child classes to inherit it.

Comment: Or perhaps is it not declared as a property, but merely set in the parent constructor that is being called late?

Comment: @volk: add please `fControllerAbstract` and show how you call all of these. For now I see exactly the same results for both cases

Comment: @volk: and slit it into two different scripts that give *different* results. From what you've already given both parts (the "WORKS" and "DOESN'T WORK") give me the same results on php 5.3

Comment: Cant reproduce http://codepad.org/kwTYaYUB

Comment: @zerkms Thats weird. The problem is that this is part of a bigger project, so i can't have you guys reproduce this per se..I'm using autoloading/a couple of separate libraries. Do you think that the field members can be somehow be interfering from MoorActionController/MoorAbstractController (they are 3rd party classes). I'm also using different variable names ("$this->view", not field_member)

Comment: So the code you pasted works just fine for you?

Comment: no, the part where it says //doesnt work// , doesnt actually work. I fixed it, but i dont know why it works now. I think this question probably isnt fit for here because this is part of a much larger project and the problem possibly lies somewhere else

Comment: Sounds like you need a fancy-shmancy editor that can do breakpoints/stepper debugging so you can track down the issue.

Comment: Try to avoid multiple levels of inheritance in the first place. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Works for me on PHP 5.2 and 5.3. Your issue lies elsewhere. Double check your code that calls `->home()`.

```
abstract class fControllerAbstract 
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

}

class fController extends fControllerAbstract
{
    protected $field_member = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->field_member = "asdasdas"; //value doesnt get passed


    }
}

class IndexController extends fController 
{

    public function beforeAction()
    {

    }

    public function home()
    {
        echo $this->field_member; 
    }
}


$ic = new IndexController();
$ic->home(); // output: asdasdas
```